# Elastic Search existing field mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search, I have created an index "cmn" with a type "mention". I am trying to import data from my existing solr to elasticsearch, so I want to map an existing field to the _id field.

I have created the following file under /config/mappings/cmn/,

```
{
    "mappings": {
    "mentions":{
        "_id" : {
            "path" : "docKey"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, every time I index a record the following _id is created,

```
        "_index": "cmn",
        "_type": "mentions",
        "_id": "k4E0dJr6Re2Z39HAIjYMmg",
        "_score": 1
```

Also, the mapping is not reflects. I have also tried the following option,

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_id" : {
            "path" : "docKey"
        }
    }
}
```

SAMPLE DOCUMENT: Basically a tweet.

```
 {
           "usrCreatedDate": "2012-01-24 21:34:47",
           "sex": "U",
           "listedCnt": 2,
           "follCnt": 432,
           "state": "Southampton",
           "classified": 0,
           "favCnt": 468,
           "timeZone": "Casablanca",
           "twitterId": 473333038,
           "lang": "en",
           "stnostem": "#ootd #ootw #fashion #styling #photography #white #pink #playsuit #prada #sunny #spring http://t.co/YbPFrXlpuh",
           "sourceId": "tw",
           "timestamp": "2014-04-09T22:58:00.396Z",
           "sentiment": 0,
           "updatedOnGMTDate": "2014-04-09T22:56:57.000Z",
           "userLocation": "Southampton",
           "age": 0,
           "priorityScore": 57.4700012207031,
           "statusCnt": 14612,
           "name": "YazzyK",
           "profilePicUrl": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/453578494556270594/orsA0pKi_normal.jpeg",
           "mentions": "",
           "sourceStripped": "Instagram",
           "collectionName": "STREAMING",
           "tags": "557/161/193/197",
           "msgid": 1397084280396.33,
           "_version_": 1464949081784713200,
           "url2": "{\"urls\":[{\"url\":\"http://t.co/YbPFrXlpuh\",\"expandedURL\":\"http://instagram.com/p/mliZbgxVZm/\",\"displayURL\":\"instagram.com/p/mliZbgxVZm/\",\"start\":88,\"end\":110}]}",
           "links": "http://t.co/YbPFrXlpuh",
           "retweetedStatus": "",
           "twtScreenName": "YazKader",
           "postId": "454030232501358592",
           "country": "Bermuda",
           "message": "#ootd #ootw #fashion #styling #photography #white #pink #playsuit #prada #sunny #spring http://t.co/YbPFrXlpuh",
           "source": "<a href=\"http://instagram.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Instagram</a>",
           "parentStatusId": -1,
           "bio": "Live and breathe Fashion. Persian and proud- Instagram: @Yazkader",
           "createdOnGMTDate": "2014-04-09T22:56:57.000Z",
           "searchText": "#ootd #ootw #fashion #styling #photography #white #pink #playsuit #prada #sunny #spring http://t.co/YbPFrXlpuh",
           "isFavorited": "False",
           "frenCnt": 214,
           "docKey": "tw_454030232501358592"
        }
```

Also, how can we create unique mapping for each "TYPE" and not just the index.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also provide the document you are indexing? And you also create a mapping per type. You cannot really create a mapping per index.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie provided a sample document,it's basically a tweet.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

Put the mapping as,

```
PUT index_name/type_name/_mapping
{
   "type_name": {
      "_id": {
         "path": "docKey"
      },
      "properties": {
         "docKey": {
            "type": "string"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And, it will work. (When you index docKey, then _id is set). You shouldn't have to provide all the mapping.